# SQL Insert progress bar

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to be able to insert a kind of progress bar to this script as it takes a while to load.

```
csvReader = csv.reader(open(fo, 'rb'), delimiter=',')
csvList = list(csvReader)
#print len(csvList)
#return
count = 1

for row in csvList[:50000]:
    if count != 1:
        cur.execute(sql2, [row[0], row[2], row[9], row[11], row[18], row[25], row[27], row[15], row[22]])
    count +=1

cnn.close()
```

Comment: you could simply `print( (count * 100)/50000 + "%")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're loading the csv data into memory - so you have its length...

```
# untested
from itertools import count
rows = len(csvList)
pctn = rows // 100
perc = count()
for rowno, row in enumerate(csvList):
    if rowno % pctn == 0:
        print '{}%'.format(next(perc))
```

On a side note, it might be worth looking into having Python just reformat the data, and use your DB's import/bulk upload mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to be able to insert a kind of progress bar to this script as it takes a while to load

python does have a progress-bar package http://code.google.com/p/python-progressbar/

once installed this is how you might use it.

```
from progressbar import  Bar, ETA, Percentage, ProgressBar, RotatingMarker

csvReader = csv.reader(open(fo, 'rb'), delimiter=',')
csvList = list(csvReader)
#print len(csvList)
#return
count = 1
widgets = ['Parsing CSV: ', Percentage(), ' ', Bar(marker = RotatingMarker()), ' ', ETA()]
pbar = ProgressBar(widgets = widgets, maxval = 50000).start()

for index, row in enumerate(csvList[:50000]):
    if count != 1:
        cur.execute(sql2, [row[0], row[2], row[9], row[11], row[18], row[25], row[27], row[15], row[22]])
    count +=1
    pbar.update(index)

pbar.finish()
cnn.close()
```

you can change the rate of the update by playing around with `maxval` and `update`.